# KiCad Footprints : What does the P stand for in footprint naming?

Tags: pcb, kicad, footprint

Newbie with KiCad. What does the P stand for in Diodes_THT:D_A-405_P2.54mm_Vertical_KathodeUp?

I am assuming it to be PAD Length, but need to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P stands for Pitch, the distance between two pins.

For more information: [KiCad Library Convention - General footprint naming conventions](http://kicad-pcb.org/libraries/klc/F2.1/)

Comment: Naming Conventions !! Ah yeah. Didn't search that. Thanks @m.Alin